# store Git credentials on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, password, git, username

How can I store my Git credentials so that I don't have to enter my username and password every time in cloning and committing?

Comment: Typically you don't. You use SSH keys. And of course the keys should have passphrases on them, but you can use the SSH agent to avoid having to provide that passphrase every time.